# Find duplicate values in XML and remove the node in XSL

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, nodes

I am having issue to find out duplicate value of element and remove the node.

XML:

```
<library>
<books>
<name>Learn XSLT</name>
<id>1</id>
</books>
<books>
<name>Learn Java</name>
<id>3</id>
</books>
<books>
<name>Learn XSLT</name>
<id>2</id>
</books>
</library>
```

I want to store the duplicate entry that is `<name>Learn XSLT</name>` and `<id>2</id>` in variable and remove that books node from XML. 
I am stuck at how to find those duplicates.

expected output
variable containing

```
<books>
    <name>Learn XSLT</name>
    <id>2</id>
    </books>
```

output XML

```
<library>
    <books>
    <name>Learn XSLT</name>
    <id>1</id>
    </books>
    <books>
    <name>Learn Java</name>
    <id>3</id>
    </books>
    </library>
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: i am using xslt

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `xsl:param` containing the XML structure to find (or selected it from somewhere, such as an external doc), you could remove the elements in which all of it's child elements match the `xsl:param` element's child elements, using `deep-equal()` to perform the comparison.

Using an [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with a specialized template to match the element to remove:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="filter">
    <books>
        <name>Learn XSLT</name>
        <id>2</id>
    </books>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--if all of the matched element's children are deep equal to the $filter element's children, 
      then remove it -->
  <xsl:template match="*[deep-equal(*, $filter/*/*)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But i might have many duplicates not just one. I cant put everything in param?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included those details in the question, but the easiest way to find out is to try it.

Comment: its like i need to remove <books>
<name>Learn XSLT</name>
<id>2</id>
</books>